# delete trigger when condition is met

Tags: mysql, triggers, sql-delete

I know it is a simple question but i am not finding the answer anywhere.

That's my table:

```
city  | CREATE TABLE `city` (
  `ID` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `Name` char(35) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `CountryCode` char(3) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `District` char(20) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `Population` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  PRIMARY KEY (`ID`),
  KEY `FKcode99` (`CountryCode`),
  CONSTRAINT `FKcode99` FOREIGN KEY (`CountryCode`) REFERENCES `country` (`code`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 |
```

**The question is: If you want to delete a city, the population must be 275,000 or less.**

**I tried**

```
ALTER TABLE `world`.`city` 
RENAME TO  `world`.`DeleteCity` ;
USE `world`;

DELIMITER $$

DROP TRIGGER IF EXISTS world.DeleteCity_ADEL$$
USE `world`$$


CREATE TRIGGER `DeleteCity_ADEL` AFTER DELETE ON `DeleteCity` FOR EACH ROW
IF (OLD.population <= 275000) THEN
    DELETE FROM city WHERE NEW.name=OLD.name;
END IF;
$$
DELIMITER ;
```

but it doesn't work. Can anybody help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would do it in this way:

```
CREATE TRIGGER `DeleteCity_ADEL` BEFORE DELETE ON `DeleteCity` FOR EACH ROW
IF (OLD.population > 275000) THEN
     SIGNAL SQLSTATE '45123'
      SET MESSAGE_TEXT = 'If you want to delete a city, the population must be 275,000 or less.';
END IF;
/
```

This trigger raises an error when somone is trying to delete a record with population > 275,000 and returns a clear explanation (error message) to him.
If population is less or equal than 275,000, the record is silently deleted.